# I want to reduce sum of "Sales Order" with "Delivery Order" by "SO NUMBER and Item Code" in foreach php excel

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, for-loop

before it i try query in sql server with partition by SO NUMBER and ITEM CODE , but i get long time when execute query because I have a lot of data

so i will try this process in frontend when print excel with php excel

form this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr4hB.png)

i want to this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GjFG.png)

this is my code

```
 $rowCount = 2;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

            //i try until this and i stuck how to reduce the SO QUANTITY with DO QUANTITY

            for ($j = 1; $j <= count($data); $j++) {
                if ($data[$i]['SONUMBER'] == $data[$j]['SONUMBER'] && $data[$i]['ITEMCODE'] == $data[$j]['ITEMCODE']) {
                }
            }

            $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $data[$i]['SONUMBER'])
                ->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $data[$i]['ITEMCODE'])
                ->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $data[$i]['SOQTY'])
                ->SetCellValue('D' . $rowCount, $data[$i]['DOQTY']);
            $rowCount++;
        }
```

Comment: if I understood this correctly you wanna change `->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $data[$i]['SOQTY'])` to `->SetCellValue('C' . ($rowCount, $data[$i]['SOQTY'] - $rowCount, $data[$i]['DOQTY']))`

Comment: if i use this code ` ->SetCellValue('H' . $rowCount, ($data[$i]['SOQTY'] - $data[$i]['DOQTY']))`, i get second data SO and DO = 256.250 || 62.500 , i want to get SO and DO = 228.750 || 62.500 , because for the second and next rows generated from the previous SO - DO
@breezer